# $\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^{-x^2/2} $ without lhospital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to ask you, how to calculate this without l hospital $$\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^{-x^2/2} $$

Comment: Why would one use the hospital?

Comment: Is it 0 becuse e^x run faster ?

Comment: It is zero because exponentials decay significantly faster than polynomials grow,

Comment: @EmoGma Use $e^{x^2/2}\ge 1+x^2/2$.

Answer (score 5):

$e^{u}\geq u$ for $u\geq 0$, so $xe^{-x^{2}/2}\leq\dfrac{x}{2^{-1}x^{2}}=\dfrac{2}{x}\rightarrow 0$.